# What device is Amazon basing their error location on?

Tags: amazon, mobi

I've always wondered where the error location in the Amazon reworks list is using when the emulator is not very good for testing and all their devices are different sizes causing pagination to become different between devices.  So my question is, since I haven't found anything mentioned in the documentation, when Amazon sends you a rework for a Mobi file with a `loc: ###` what device are they basing the `loc` on?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a rework, so I can't be certain what the format is, but my guess is that they are not using display pages, which would be specific to particular devices as you mention. Instead, I would think they are using their location numbers. There is [a lot of speculation](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle/Tx2S4K44LSXEWRI?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG) about where those numbers come from, but the consensus seems to be that each one represents 128 bytes of data.